# Where is Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu Sotware app has suddenly disappeared from my programs. I haven't done anything or so I believe. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in a Dell Laptop. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried starting it from the terminal to check whether or not it is installed?

```
ubuntu-software
```

If it's not installed you should look at this

[How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it wasn't installed. So I installed it again from the terminal and it worked. Although I can't come to understand how it was uninstalled in the first place.